# Enlarge text before read more line in k2 article

Tags: articles, k2, fonts

I am using the K2 extension for articles.

In the beginning of each article I leave a little text (teaser) then insert the 'Read More' line.

When I go inside the article and click on the plus next to 'font size', in order to increase the scale of the text, only the text after the 'read more' line gets changed.

Is there a way to enlarge the text before the read more line along with the whole article text in K2 articles?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a style change in the site. You can just edit your template style and change the general font size, or define a specify CSS statement for K2.

Check in the template manager, what options you template features support, or manully customize the stylesheet. Most templates provide a way to override or add new styles.